# Django importing another file from another package

Tags: python, django

I have the following folder structure

```
app/
app/helpers/
app/helpers/methodhelper.py
app/methods/
app/methods/method.py
```

and I'm trying to import a function from methodhelper.py inside method.py 
so I tried the following:

```
import app.helpers.methodhelper
OR
from app.helpers.methodhelper import function1
OR
import helpers.methodhelper
```

and I get:

```
"No module named app.helpers.methodhelper"
```

Important to note: `helpers/__init__.py` already exists

How should this be done ?

Comment: I get this error when I go to app/methods with console and run "python -i method.py"

Comment: Does `app/__init__.py` exist?

Comment: how about `from helpers.methodhelper import function1` , I m guessing, the issue is with the way `manage.py` is defined

Comment: What does your PYTHONPATH look like?

Comment: @orokusaki app/__init__.py exists, karthikr -  same message.
 is it important that there's no class in methodhelper.py but just a few functions defined ?

Comment: It does not matter. Either ways it should pick it up

Comment: "echo $PYTHONPATH" returns nothing, odd.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Your Django project's default path is in the root directory of the project (where the manage.py file is). You can either add the sub directories below that to your PYTHONPATH (easily done by appending to sys.path) or you can import that function using the full module path:

`from projectname.app.helpers.methodhelper import function1`

When I start a Django project, I always add

`PROJECT_ROOT = os.path.abspath(os.path.join(os.path.dirname(__file__), '..'))`

to my `settings.py`. This path looks similar to `/home/kyle/django_project_name/`. Inside that directly is `manage.py`.

From there, also in my `settings.py`, I include:

`sys.path.append(os.path.join(PROJECT_ROOT, 'django_project_name'))`

This makes my apps importable without the need to include my project name in the module path.

Comment: Yes, `from app.helpers.methodhelper import function1` should work, I just tested that.

Comment: it seems that my Eclipse console doesn't include the PYTHONPATH to the project, odd.. it is working now when I use KDE Konsole.. ideas about automatically adding the path into the Eclipse console?

Comment: @Asaf is the Eclipse console just a python REPL? If so, you can just import sys and append to sys.path

Comment: You should have something like this under Window -> Preferences.


  [1]: http://i.stack.imgur.com/Iwy30.png

Answer (score 0):

you need to add the module in **settings.py** file