# Django: ModuleNotFoundError: no module named 'Parser'

Tags: python, django, import, virtualenv, python-import

In my project, I have an app called pages:

```
apps/pages/experiments
```

Within experiments, the relevant files are:

- models.py
- a folder called parser (which includes an empty file init.py (with 4 underscores)

The folder called parser has python code that I would like to import in models, and use there. I have a line of code:

```
from parser import Tables
```

However, when I run the command

```
python manage.py runserver
```

I get the following error:

```
from parser import Tables
ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'XML_parser'
```

edit: I just realized that If I remove imports of my own code, and simply try to import models.py within views.py, then I also get the same error, but now "models.py" instead of parser

Comment: You tagged the question with `virtualenv` so I assume you use one. Did you activate it before `runserver`?

Comment: I'm using the anaconda virtual environment for Django. I was able to run the server prior to importing any code from parser, so I think it's fine

Answer (score 0):

Try to run `makemigrations` and `migrate` after defining your app name in settings.INSTALLED_APPS

```py
INSTALLED_APPS = [
    # ...
    'Abc.apps.AbcConfig' // Replace your app's name with 'Abc'
```

```py
python manage.py makemigrations
python manage.py migrate
```

Answer (score 0):

as it turns out, i have to start importing from the base of my django project:

[Django importing another file from another package](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16530728/django-importing-another-file-from-another-package)