# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named <module-name>

Tags: python-3.x, django, package, python-import, python-packaging

I have a package named ImgUtils in my project directory, which looks something like this:

```
├── myproject
│   ├── test.py
│   ├── Analyzer
│      ├── __init__.py
│      ├── utils.py
│      └── ImgUtils
│          ├── __init__.py
│          ├── ImgUtils.pyd
│          ├── ImgUtils.so
│          └── a bunch of *.dll files
```

`ImgUtils.pyd` exports a class called `PyImageUtils`.

```py
\\ utils.py
from ImgUtils.ImgUtils import PyImageUtils

def my_test_function():
    a = PyImageUtils.analyze()
    return a
```

```py
\\ test.py
from Analyzer import utils

print(utils.my_test_function())
```

The import in `utils.py` works fine, but if I run `test.py`, I get `ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'PyImgUtils'`.

I am using Python 3.10. The path to `ImgUtils.pyd` is in the `sys.path` list.

Comment: What's the root directory from which you start jupyter notebook vs root directory from which you execute your python script directly?

Comment: @matszwecja The root directories are the same in both cases. But the jupyter notebook runs in a conda environment, whereas the script doesn't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**UPDATE**: I was able to solve this by importing ImgUtils like so:

```py
\\ utils.py

from myproject.Analyzer.ImgUtils.ImgUtils import PyImageUtils
```

I was using Django and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/16531175/9864448) answer explains the solution.